# Flicker when custom css cursor in specific position?

Tags: jquery, css

See snippet below.

When `offsetx` and `offsety` are 20 or higher, it looks fine.  However when I try to set them to 5, which seems to line up perfectly to me, there is a significant "flicker".  Is there anything I can do about it?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  offsetx = 5;
    offsety = 5;
  $('#oy').html("offsety=" + offsety);
  $('#ox').html("offsetx=" + offsetx);
    $('#area1').mouseout(function(){
        $('#c1').hide();
        return false;
    }).mouseenter(function(){
        $('#c1').show();
        return false;
    }).mousemove(function(e){
        $('#c1').css('left', e.clientX - offsetx).css('top', e.clientY - offsety);
    });
});

$('#toggle').on('click',function() {
 if ($('#toggle').html() == 'Exact') {
   $('#toggle').html('Offset');
    offsetx = 5;
    offsety = 5;
 } else {
   $('#toggle').html('Exact');
    offsetx = 25;
    offsety = 15;
 }
  $('#oy').html("offsety=" + offsety);
  $('#ox').html("offsetx=" + offsetx);
})
```

```css
#area1 {
 height: 50px;
 border: 3px dashed #CCCCCC;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 padding: 20px;
 cursor: none;
}

#toggle { cursor: pointer; padding: 3px; border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 10px;}
#c1 {
 cursor: none;
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 10000;
 background: #000;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="c1"></div>    
<div id="area1"></div>
<br>
<span id="toggle">Offset</span><span><- Click to toggle</span>
<br><br>
<div id="oy"></div>
<div id="ox">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding

```
 pointer-events: none;
```

to your CSS rule for #c1.

Haven't tried it, but it may fix your problem. I'm not sure if pointer-events is supported in all browsers though.

Comment: This breaks css `:hover` and jquery on hover.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: Exactly. And that's the reason your ball is not flickering. Since pointer-events=none cancels ALL mouse events on #c1, #area1 is not receiving mouseout and mouseenter events when the cursor is on top of #c1 (which happens when its position overlaps the mouse coordinates).

Comment: I managed to get it all working.  Thanks.  http://i.imgur.com/ojAZ70P.gifv

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two changes. First change your event from `mouseout` to `mouseleave`, secondly, restructure your HTML such that `#c1` is within `#area`.

Essentially what is happening is that the `#c1` element is outside of the `#area` element so when it shows up under your mouse your mouse has "moved out" of the `#area` element. Thus it hides it and you get the weird flickering behavior.

Updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/etjs7gLL/2/

Comment: In your fiddle, if I move the mouse at a reasonable rate, it never changes back to the cursor.

Comment: What do you mean?